# DCOM update error in wine

Tags: wine

I am trying to install araxis merge through wine. I get the following error **"You need to install DCOM update on this computer"**. The following are details of my configuration.

1. Operating System: Linux with Fedora12 (32 bit machine)
2. Wine Version: Wine-1.2
3. Trying to install "merge65_win32_1624" file.

Any thoughts to overcome this error are welcome.